# How to write to HDFS using kedro

Tags: python, hdfs, pipeline, kedro

I'm trying to output of my Kedro pipeline to the HDFS file system. But I couldn't see on the internet how to do that and on Kedro documents. If anybody configured kedro in catalog please share a sample code how to do that.

Also how to connect hdfs securely using credentials

I have the data in panda dataframe.

How the entry for this catalog.yml looks like and where do I mention the credentials

Answer (score 0):

In your catalog you can define filepath like `hdfs://user@server:port/path/to/data`

https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data/data_catalog.html#specifying-the-location-of-the-dataset

Comment: Also how to connect hdfs securely using credentials

I have the data in panda dataframe.

How the entry for this catalog.yml looks like and where do I mention the credentials

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can write to hdfs from outside Kedro (standalone spark) , this should be straightforward from Kedro.

Use the `sparkDataSet` in your catalog file and define the properties like hive meta store etc in `spark.yml` and that should be it

Then, Like Rahul mentioned above you need to specify the full path to the `hdfs` location you want to write to , if you are still facing issues , please share some snapshots

```
dataset_name:
  type: spark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: hdfs://your_bucket/location/file.parq
```

Comment: Do you mean to add sparkDataSet on catalog.yml?

Comment: Yes , ive pasted a snip in my comment above